# c program is compiling and running but I am getting a weird output in the terminal

Tags: c, string, output

so I have a method that moves a string from a file to a char array in c, but when I try to print it out I am getting a weird output in the terminal that looks like a bunch of for each char spot and each box has 4 0's and 1's.

Here's the my code:

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv){
            if(argc != 3){
                    printf("not valid # of arguments");
                    return 1;
            }
            struct stat info;
            int status;
            status = stat(argv[2], &info);

            if(status != 0){
                    printf("Error, errno = %d\n", errno);
                    return 1;
            }
            //command line argument is file
            if(S_ISREG (info.st_mode)){
                    printf("%s is a file \n", argv[2]);
                    char *string1;
                    string1  = getFileString(argv[2]);
                    printf("string in file is %s \n", string1);
                    free(string1);
                    return 0;
            }
            if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)){
                    printf("%s is a directory \n", argv[2]);
                    openDirRec(argv[2]);
                    //what to do if command line argument is directory
            }
            return 0;


    }
    char* getFileString(char *fileName){
        FILE* qp;
        qp = fopen(fileName, "r");
        char ch;
        struct stat st;
        if(stat(fileName, &st) != 0) {
        return NULL;
        }
        /*int sizeCheck = 0;
        while((ch=fgetc(qp))!=EOF){
                sizeCheck++;
        }
        */
        int sizeCheck = st.st_size;
        if(sizeCheck == 0){
                return NULL;
        }
        else{
                //fseek(qp, SEEK_SET, 0);
                char *fileString;
                fileString = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeCheck + 1);
                memset(fileString, 0, sizeCheck + 1);
                //rewind(qp);
                int count = 0;
                while((ch=fgetc(qp)!=EOF)){
                        fileString[count] = ch;
                        count++;
                }
                printf("%s\n", fileString);
                fileString[sizeCheck] = '\0';
                fclose(qp);
                return fileString;

}
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is defined to be `1`; no sense in multiplying by it. Also, *always* check the result of `malloc` for `NULL`. Also, `stat` is already telling you the size of the file; your `sizeCheck++` loop is very inefficient and unnecessary. Also, look into `fread`; calling `fgetc` for every character is also inefficient. Also, you may want to `NUL`-terminate your string *before* printing it. Also, are you *sure* your file is only ASCII characters? Also, now is as good a time as ever to learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: can this cause an off by one , fileString[sizeCheck + 1] = '\0';
?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart yeah I am using gdb and when i checked  gdb before modifying my code the first loop to count with ch actually read the characters, i got rid of that and used the stat struct and got the size that way but all the chars in the loop for putting the characters in the array are coming up as '\001' and its still outputing the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the culprit.

```
            while((ch=fgetc(qp)!=EOF))
```

Due to operator precedence, that is equivalent to:

```
            while(ch = (fgetc(qp)!=EOF) )
```

what you need is a little rearrangement of the parantheses.

```
            while((ch=fgetc(qp)) != EOF)
```

Comment: You're right it works perfectly now! I can't believe I spent hours on this because of that thank you so much!